# Parsing complex GML with GDAL

Tags: gdal, gml

We have some complex GML that looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<abpr:AddressBaseSupplySet
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd"
    xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco"
    xmlns:gss="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gss"
    xmlns:gts="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gts"
    xmlns:gsr="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gsr"
    xmlns:abpr="http://namespaces.geoplace.co.uk/addressbasepremium/2.1"
    xmlns:gmlxbt="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.3/xbt" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2 http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd http://namespaces.geoplace.co.uk/addressbasepremium/2.1 http://www.geoplace.co.uk/addressbase/schema/2.1/addressbasepremium.xsd" gml:id="FC1">
    <gml:description>Ordnance Survey (c) Crown Copyright. All rights reserved, 2024 and produced by GeoPlace</gml:description>
    <gml:boundedBy>
        <gml:Envelope srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::27700">
            <gml:lowerCorner>340000 1010000</gml:lowerCorner>
            <gml:upperCorner>345000 1015000</gml:upperCorner>
        </gml:Envelope>
    </gml:boundedBy>
    <abpr:queryTime>2024-01-19T00:00:03.000</abpr:queryTime>
    <abpr:basicLandPropertyUnitMember>
        <abpr:BasicLandPropertyUnit gml:id="uk.addressbase.uprn.134015095">
            <abpr:changeType>I</abpr:changeType>
            <abpr:organisationMember>
                <abpr:Organisation>
                    <abpr:organisation>Org number 1</abpr:organisation>
                    <abpr:endDate>2001-01-01</abpr:endDate>
                </abpr:Organisation>
            </abpr:organisationMember>
            <abpr:organisationMember>
                <abpr:Organisation>
                    <abpr:organisation>Org number 2</abpr:organisation>
                </abpr:Organisation>
            </abpr:organisationMember>
            <abpr:organisationMember>
                <abpr:Organisation>
                    <abpr:organisation>Org number 3</abpr:organisation>
                    <abpr:endDate>2003-03-03</abpr:endDate>
                </abpr:Organisation>
            </abpr:organisationMember>
        </abpr:BasicLandPropertyUnit>
    </abpr:basicLandPropertyUnitMember>
</abpr:AddressBaseSupplySet>
```

You can see we have some three nested 'organisationMember's, two have 'endDate's, with the middle not having one.

When we parse this GML with GDAL even supplying our own GFS file it gets converted to.

```
"organisation": ["Org number 1", "Org number 2", "Org number 3"],
"endDate": ["2001-01-01", "2003-03-03"]
```

The result of this is that the indexOf the endDate doesn't align to the organisation any more. Reading the docs I have tried using as many of the different open options and configurations options including READ_MODE, GML_ATTRIBUTES_TO_OGR_FIELDS but I just don't think there is a way to ensure that the indexOf order is kept somehow.

Comment: The more advanced GML driver GMLAS prints two times this warning. `ogrinfo GMLAS:gml.gml --debug on  :  Warning 1: Unexpected element abpr:BasicLandPropertyUnit/abpr:organisationMember/abpr:Organisation/abpr:endDate`. It is only a warning so maybe it does not mean any issue in the schema.

Comment: Maybe the GDAL GML driver cannot handle this case. Only workaround that worked for me was to edit the data to have some endDate for all Organisations with something like `<abpr:endDate>null</abpr:endDate>`. The GMLAS driver https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/gmlas.html could probably do better job. However, by looking at the XML schemas I think that Organisation should not have endDate at all and GMLAS may not be happy because of that. I may be wrong, I am not goot at reading XML schemas.

Comment: @user30184 the GML snippet above was a hack from an existing file to be used for testing, so it doesn't have all the parts (including mandatory ones) which the schema would expect. So you are not reading it wrong at all. Having done some significant tests with the GMLAS today I think this is definitely the way to go. It is able to comprehend the hierarchical structure and explodes the 1-to-many relationships which allow for the NULL values for the endDate. I need to do some further reviews but it is looking promising, so thank you.